# Get a list of keywords sorted according to certain criteria in Google Adwords

Tags: google-adwords

Is there anyway I can obtain a list of keywords sorted according to certain criteria in Google Adwords?

For example, I want to obtain a list of sorted keywords with the highest local month search/CPC, is there anyway to obtain this statistic?